# How to deal with missing values when exporting data from R to SAS?

Tags: r, sas

I have a bit of experience working with R but am completely new to SAS but I need it to run certain analyses that I was advised SAS would be able to handle better.

I currently have a dataset that I cleaned up in R that has 552 variables, all are numeric. Some of the numeric variables have missing values and I am struggling to figure out how to bring these over to SAS because from what I understand, SAS only recognizes "." as a missing value. I exported the R data into a CSV file and then imported that into SAS. However, if I recode all NAs in R to ".", then they become character variables and once they are imported into SAS, they seem to appear as character. However, if I leave them as NAs, then SAS recognizes them as character anyways.

Has anyone dealt with this issue? My options I think are:

1. Leave the missing value as NA but recode all 500+ variables at one time once they are in SAS (I saw a few comments on how to recode variables individually from character to numeric in SAS but I'd rather not have to do it one by one and I'm sure there's a more efficient way).
2. Figure out a way to be able to export the file from R --> csv --> SAS by keeping the variables numeric (I also don't mind using another approach that doesn't require csv, that's just all I was able to find).

If anyone knows a lot about R or SAS (or both) to help me with this issue, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

I'm not sure if this is useful/relevant info but my goal once in SAS is to use the procLCA & procLTA packages to run latent class models.

Comment: Both `.` (in SAS) and `NA` in R  are not missing values themselves, but *human-readable representations* of missing values.  That's why you're not succeeding at the moment.  There are packages that allow you to import to and export from SAS and R.  Have you looked at `foreign`?  That might help avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: **Specify an empty string for missing values when exporting the CSV from R, using the `na = ''` argument to `write.csv()`. SAS will recognize this as a missing value.**

I tested the following (file paths are omitted from the code). First here is R code to write a CSV with some missing values and export it.

```
foo <- data.frame(X = c('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'goo'), Y = c(5, NA, 6, NA), Z = c('a', NA, NA, 'b'))
write.csv(foo, 'foo.csv', row.names = FALSE, na = '')
```

Next SAS code to import the CSV and examine the contents to make sure the numeric column was interpreted as numeric with missing values.

```
proc import datafile='foo.csv' out=dat dbms=csv replace; run;

proc contents data=dat; run;
proc means data=dat nmiss; run;
```

The `proc contents` output shows the correct column types:

```
Alphabetic List of Variables and Attributes 
# Variable Type Len Format Informat 
1 X Char 5 $5. $5. 
2 Y Num 8 BEST12. BEST32. 
3 Z Char 3 $3. $3.
```

The `proc means` output with `nmiss` shows the correct number of missing values in the numeric column. (See [this post](https://www.statology.org/sas-count-missing-values/) for how to count missing values in the character columns.)

```
Analysis
Variable
: Y  
N Miss 
2
```

Comment: @user21027866 if this answered your question, please consider accepting the answer (green check mark) to notify other users that this is the best answer.